# How to resolve Error while building Passthrough stream java.util.zip.ZipException in WSo2 Gateway?

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am getting the following error on the WSo2 Gateway 2.1.0 when trying to pass a response back to WSo2 EI that originated an API call on APIM and I am not sure what the issue is:

````
[2021-05-06 15:19:26,401] ERROR org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils:344 -  Error while building Passthrough stream
java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165)
        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79)
        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:91)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.handleGZip(HTTPTransportUtils.java:262)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:151)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:114)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:78)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.LogsHandler.buildResponseMessage_aroundBody16(LogsHandler.java:264)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.LogsHandler.buildResponseMessage(LogsHandler.java:254)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.LogsHandler.handleResponseInFlow_aroundBody6(LogsHandler.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.LogsHandler.handleResponseInFlow(LogsHandler.java:131)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.invokeHandlers(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:1077)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:242)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:556)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:186)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:265)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at datadog.trace.bootstrap.instrumentation.java.concurrent.Wrapper.run(Wrapper.java:25)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

There can be some possible scenarios for the above issue.

1. **Content-Encoding: gzip** header comes in the response header but the content of the response is not in GZIP format. You can verify that by enabling the wire logs.
   You can get rid of this behavior by removing the **Content-Encoding** header using header mediator as shown below before calling the EI endpoint.

```
<header action="remove" name="Content-Encoding" scope="transport"/>
```

2. The client(according to your case it's EI) is expecting the content encoded as gzip while the APIM is serving it deflated or some other way.
   So in such a case, You can use the below property to send the response in gzip format

```
    <property name="Content-Encoding" value="gzip" scope="transport"/>
```

Comment: are both scenarios you suggested requiring that property to be added to the EI Application?

Comment: If the API call is originated from APIM, you have to add the relevant property in the APIM level.